# Interfacing Matllab with Arduino Nano CH340

Tags: matlab, arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-ide

I am trying to interface an Arduino Nano CH340 with Matlab but keep getting this error:

> Error using ArduinoMatlabExampleYT (line 11)
> Cannot program board Nano33BLE (COM3). Please make sure the board is supported and the port and board type are correct. For more information,
> see Arduino Hardware Troubleshooting.

I tried `Nano3`, `Nano33IoT`, and `Nano33BLE`, but all failed. below is the basic code in Matlab.

Also, the Arduino package is installed.

```
clear
clc
close all

ledPin = 'D13';
deltaT_blink = 0.5;

port = 'COM3';
board = 'Nano3';

a = arduino(port, board);

for k=1:10
    a.writeDigitalPin(ledPin,0);
    pause(deltaT_blink/2);
    
    a.writeDigitalPin(ledPin,1);
    pause(deltaT_blink/2);
end
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Which tutorial are you following?

Comment: Please copy paste the code into the question as text, not an image.

Comment: @GabrielStaples https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8NQ1h0gGgX8

Comment: Nano33IoT and Nano33BLE are completely different boards from Nano with CH340.

Comment: I suspect you have the wrong board name. None of `Nano3`, `Nano33IoT`, and `Nano33BLE` seem correct for the basic `nano` board.

Comment: And you error says "Nano33BLE" but your code has "Nano3".

Comment: @GabrielStaples I tried those 3 as when I checked with MathWorks those are the 3 that somehow relate with Nano.  https://www.mathworks.com/help/supportpkg/arduinoio/ref/arduino.html

Comment: @gre_gor yes you're right, that's because I tried with all three of them, Nano3, Nano33IoT, and Nano33BLE, and all gave me the same error. (obviously with instead on Nano33BLE it mentioned the others)

Comment: @GabrielStaples ["Nano3" refers to "Arduino Nano 3.1"](https://www.mathworks.com/help/supportpkg/arduinoio/ref/arduino.html#mw_c00e99d2-1165-443e-8dce-595596a641a4) which is the basic Nano.

Comment: Are you sure COM3 is the right port? Do you have the CH340 drivers installed and working? Does it work with Arduino IDE?

Comment: @GabrielStaples Do you know the Input Argument for Nano CH340?

Comment: @Pix, Nano CH340 is a Chinese clone. It's probably version 2.x of the Arduino Nano schematic, and is probably not supported by Matlab. It looks like the official nano is now schematic version 3.3. Go here (https://store-usa.arduino.cc/products/arduino-nano/) and click the ["SCHEMATICS IN .PDF"](https://content.arduino.cc/assets/NanoV3.3_sch.pdf) link.

Comment: Try uploading the Uno bootloader to your Nano and selecting "Uno" as the board. I've used the Uno bootloader on that board before. You'll need an ICSP programmer to do this, such as the USBasp programmer, or another Arduino running the ["Arduino as ISP"](https://docs.arduino.cc/built-in-examples/arduino-isp/ArduinoISP) sketch.

Comment: @gre_gor yes I uploaded a program through Arduino IDE already, hence the com port is good. I also tried to close the Arduino IDE so there will be no conflicts between Matlab and IDE. Matlab is finding the board as when I Run code through Matlab the Nano is blinking and a message is showing (Updating server code on board Nano3(COM3). This may take a few minutes.),  but after a while, it fails and displays the said error.

Comment: @Pix Edit all that info into the question.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Remember to upvote any useful answer, and mark correct with the green checkmark an answer if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the hardware to test this, nor the Matlab software to test this at this time, but here are some ideas. Try them in this order:

1. Since your Nano is a Chinese clone, set the board in Matlab to `ProMini328_5V`. I got that name from this list here: https://www.mathworks.com/help/supportpkg/arduinoio/ug/find-board-name.html. It is also stated to work on this forum here: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/494451-problem-connecting-to-arduino-nano-3-0#answer_404385. If it works, it is because the Pro Mini uses the same ATmega328 microcontroller IC as the Nano, and since the Pro Mini does *not* come with a built-in UART chip, Matlab might theoretically support a variety of UARTs that you might use on this board, the CH340 included. So, I suspect selecting this board would work.
2. Upload the latest Nano bootloader to the Nano.(Do NOT skip this step! The latest Nano bootloader may be what is missing to make it work for you with Matlab.)
3. Ensure you can upload to the Nano using the Arduino IDE.
4. Ensure you upload the Matlab Arduino Server code to the Arduino: https://www.mathworks.com/help/supportpkg/arduinoio/ug/configure-setup-for-arduino-hardware.html

The Nano CH340 is a Chinese clone. It's probably version 2.x of the Arduino Nano schematic, and is probably not supported by Matlab since they say they support Nano version 3.x. It looks like the official nano is now schematic version 3.3. Go here (https://store-usa.arduino.cc/products/arduino-nano/) and click the ["SCHEMATICS IN .PDF"](https://content.arduino.cc/assets/NanoV3.3_sch.pdf) link to see.

So, if it doesn't work at a "Nano", flash the Uno bootloader to the Nano and treat the Nano as an Uno, redoing all steps as though it was an Uno. The Uno bootloader *must* be on the Nano for this to work.

I've used the Uno bootloader on that board before. You'll need an ICSP programmer to do this, such as the USBasp programmer, or another Arduino running the ["Arduino as ISP"](https://docs.arduino.cc/built-in-examples/arduino-isp/ArduinoISP) sketch.

Lastly, if you still can't get the Matlab code to work, abandon the Matlab server idea and just send raw serial commands to and from the Arduino. This is more advanced but gives you full flexibility. You'll need to write Matlab code to send serial data, and Arduino code to parse and interpret it. I have a demo of doing that many years ago here:

https://www.instructables.com/Arduino-to-MATLAB-GUI-Live-Data-Acquisition-Plotti/

Answer (score 0):

The CH40 based Arduino Nano is indeed incompatible and requires the processor option **"ATmega328P (Old Bootloader)"** under **"Tools"** in the Arduino IDE.

If your Simulink model builds, but fails to upload with an error like this then you can directly upload the *.hex* file:
**The following error occurred during deployment to your hardware board:
Failed to connect to Arduino board.**

1. Ensure the Nano is working using the Arduino IDE installed with the Simulink Hardware support package.  Somewhere like here:

C:\ProgramData\MATLAB\SupportPackages\R2020b\3P.instrset\arduinoide.instrset\arduino.exe

2. In the Arduino IDE set your board, port, and processor in **Tools>Board**, **Tools>Processor**, and **Tools>Port**.
3. Under File>Preferences check the box for **"Show verbose output during: upload"**
4. Upload a test file like the "blink" program from "examples" and, if successful, then scroll up to find the avrdude command at the top like this:

C:\ProgramData\MATLAB\SupportPackages\R2020b\3P.instrset\arduinoide.instrset\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avrdude -CC:\ProgramData\MATLAB\SupportPackages\R2020b\3P.instrset\arduinoide.instrset\hardware\tools\avr/etc/avrdude.conf -v -patmega328p -carduino -PCOM4 -b57600 -D -Uflash:w:***C:\Users\200000~1\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_62007/Blink.ino.hex***:i

5. In the Matlab command prompt copy that avrdude command and replace the path and .hex filename with the one created by Simulink and add the system prompt "!" at the beginning like this:

**!C:\ProgramData\MATLAB\SupportPackages\R2020b\3P.instrset\arduinoide.instrset\hardware\tools\avr/bin/avrdude -CC:\ProgramData\MATLAB\SupportPackages\R2020b\3P.instrset\arduinoide.instrset\hardware\tools\avr/etc/avrdude.conf -v -patmega328p -carduino -PCOM4 -b57600 -D -Uflash:w:C:\Users\200000~1\Documents\MATLAB\Examples\R2020b\arduino\GettingStartedWithArduinoRHardwareExample/arduino_gettingstarted.hex:i**

6. Should receive response at the end:
   **avrdude done.  Thank you.**

Comment: Also ensure your path doesn't have any whitespace in it,  " " or the Simulink build will fail.